# Need advice on code snippet

Tags: c, algorithm

I wrote an "insert" function to insert an integer into an array of integers. It works, but I don't know if it's the best algorithm.

Here's my code:

```
int* insert(int *dest, size_t len, unsigned int index, int value)
{
int x = 0, i = 0;
int *stackp = calloc(len+1, sizeof(int));

if(index > (len-1)) return dest;

while(x < len) {
    if(x == index) {
        ++x;
    } else {
        *(stackp+x) = *(dest+i);
        ++x, ++i;
    }
}

*(stackp+index) = value;
free(dest);
dest = stackp;

return dest;

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest returning allocated memory (as the below answers have suggested), because it is an easy way to leak memory.

Comment: @Alex, I suggested it as one possibility, along with letting the caller allocate.  I think both are fine as long as the function documentation clearly specifies it.

Comment: true, but it seems that all standard functions, and winAPI functions, prefer the latter.

Comment: @Alex, [`strdup`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) (and Microsoft's non-standard [`_strdup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) equivalent) and [`getline`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), both part of the POSIX standard, all allocate memory.

Comment: no, getline() stores its result in a buffer provided by the programmer. Don't know about strdup, never used it.

Comment: Strdup does allocate memory, and getline stores it in the buffer provided. (Also, please stay on topic. :P)

Comment: I would say that returning allocated memory is mostly all right, but in Windows you need to be aware that the library and the program can be linked to different instances of MSVCRT (for example, the program to a dll and the library statically), and this means that they are using different malloc arenas. Memory allocated by the library in this case cannot be freed by the program. Jeffrey Richter's book explains this I seem to remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a major bug in your memory allocation.  `stackp` is an automatic (stack) array, which means its lifetime ends as soon as insert returns.  You have to use another allocation method.  You can have the caller allocate a new array and pass in both pointers, or you can do it yourself with `malloc` (don't forget to free).

However, the rest looks all right.  That's pretty much the only algorithm for a non in-place insert.  You may be able to do it a bit faster with special tricks (e.g. copying two ints at once).  `memmove` and `memcopy` may use such optimizations on some architectures.

Also, many algorithms would write `stackp[index]` when the position is found, rather than at the end.  But the core algorithm is basically the same.

An alternative would be to do the insert in-place (shifting only elements after the insert position), rather than using a new array.  You would often expand with `realloc`.  This would be preferred in many situations as it saves copying time and avoids `malloc`ing a new memory location (which may also fragment the heap).

Finally, an alternative data structure entirely is a linked list.  This totally eliminates the need for copying elements, but uses more memory and prevents random access.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the opinion! Performance is not a (critical) issue in this case, so I won't try to optimize my brains out.

Answer (score 2):

There is a serious error here. The array stackp is a local variable, and you are returning it as the result. You will probably get a segmentation fault if you want to read/write that array again, outside the "insert" function.

To correct it, you need to allocate a dynamic array like:

`int *stackp;`

stackp = (int*)malloc(size(int)*(len+1));

Comment: True, I hadn't noticed that! (It's very, very late here. :P) Also, I believe it's sizeof(int) rather than size(int). Thanks!

Comment: Right, it should be sizeof :)

Comment: Do not cast the return value of `malloc`!

Comment: You can cast the value of malloc, but the Standard deems it unnecessary. In the old days, though, you had to cast it. Nowadays, it's just a habit. Don't say stuff like this based on a religious basis (Religious as in goto is bad, K&R indent is bad, etc.).